# HP Envy 17.3 Touchscreen 64bit - Shows "No pen or touch input is available"

Tags: laptop, drivers, touchscreen

I am praying that someone can help me!

I have an HP Envy 17.3 Touchscreen laptop that I purchased in 2016. I purchased this model specifically for the size of the screen and the touchscreen. I didn't use it for about a year and updated everything in January. Now the touchscreen doesn't work and the system says there's no pen or touch input available.

I have spent countless hours installing/uninstalling countless drivers and my touchscreen still doesn't work. I'm thinking that I somehow deleted a driver but maybe it's something else...

Using Windows 10, version 1903.

I'd appreciate any guidance!

Thank you!

Comment: Let's test to see if the problem is in Windows or hardware.  Download Lubuntu   @ https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours  and check for download errors by  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu . Make a Linux LiveUSB (4GB or larger flash drive needed, and it _will_ be erased by this..) on your PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows w/ the Rufus Windows open source app. Reboot the PC, choose the LiveUSB from your Boot Manager after POST finishes, & run Lubuntu's apps to test.

Comment: Open Device Manager, and look at the Display to see if Device Manager sees a Touch Screen.  If you never used it, are you sure the computer came with one?

Comment: I am betting that you are just missing the touchscreen driver.  Device manager should show an icon with a yellow exclamation point next to it if this is the case.  BTW, nice laptop!